# How to test if output to std::cout (connected to a pipe) will block

Tags: c++, ipc, pipe

I have a C++ program that is launched by another executable that ingests the output of that program via a pipe. In certain conditions, the parent process reads slower than the child writes, and the child blocks when the pipe buffer in the pipe manager (QNX) becomes full.

Is there a standard way to test if cout << will block or not when it is connected to a pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, detecting that is operating-system specific.

Answer (score 1):

For QNX I'm pretty sure that [select](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/s/select.html)/[poll](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/p/poll.html) should do the trick.